# Is it possible to have custom-shaped canvas in Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to have canvas in Fabric.js custom shape. For example circle or triangle. So the user is restricted only to this circle shape and overflow of it is naturally hidden just like using standard rectangular canvas.

I couldn't figure it out from documentation and tutorials of Fabric.js. Can anyone help me find a way ?

For explaining why I need this - I want to let my users design their own fabric labels for clothing and we have different label shapes, not only rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

my demo:

```js
// Initialize set canvas size
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
});
// Ellipse
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/1.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 20,
        top: 20,
        clipPath: new fabric.Ellipse({
            rx: 70,
            ry: 50,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        })
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// Circle
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/2.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 300,
        top: 20,
        clipPath: new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 60,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
        })
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// Rounded rectangle
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/3.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 550,
        top: 20,
        clipPath: new fabric.Rect({
            width:120,
            height:100,
            rx:20,
            ry:20,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
        })
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// Triangle
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/4.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 20,
        top: 200,
        clipPath: new fabric.Triangle({
            width: 100, // 底边宽度
            height: 100, // 底边到定点的距离
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
        })
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// The native capabilities of canvas are suitable for tailoring. Version 4.2.0 does not work, but 2.6.0 can achieve the effect.
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/4.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 300,
        top: 200,
        clipTo: function (ctx) {  
            ctx.arc(0, 0, 60, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);//裁剪圆形
        }
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// Polygons don't work.
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/4.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 300,
        top: 200,
        clipPath:new fabric.Polygon([
            {x: 300, y: 200},
            {x: 500, y: 320},
            {x: 500, y: 400},
            {x: 320, y: 380}
        ],{
            backgroundColor:'#cccccc',
            opacity:0.6,
            stroke:'#6639a6',
            strokeWidth:2,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center'
        })
    })
    console.log(img)
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})
// The line segment does not work
fabric.Image.fromURL('../public/img/4.jfif',img => {
    img.set({
        left: 550,
        top: 200,
        clipPath:new fabric.Polyline([
            {x:450,y:450},
            {x:530,y:450},
            {x:450,y:530},
            {x:530,y:530},
        ],{
            stroke:'#6639a6',
            strokeWidth:2
        })
    })
    canvas.add(img)
    canvas.renderAll()
})

// Set the background of the canvas
canvas.setBackgroundColor('pink', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas))
```

Comment: Could you please make a working JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).